# Grails Spring Security manually trigger onAuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: spring, grails

I have some code that is manually authenticating a user, but I want this to also trigger the logic contained in the onAuthenticationSuccessEvent. The code that I have right now looks like this:

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(user.username)
authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, springSecurityService.getAuthentication())
```

It logs the user in fine, but does not trigger the onAuthenticationSuccessEvent like I thought it would. I figured the call to authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess would trigger this, but it doesn't. How can I get this event to trigger while logging in manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always ask that an authentication successful event through the [DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.html) be published. For example in a service you could:

```
class MyService {
  def authenticationEventPublisher
  def springSecurityService
  ...
  void someMethod() {
    ...
    authenticationEventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(
      springSecurityService.getAuthentication()
    )
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It's all documented in the Spring Security API and Spring framework.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'd been googling and debugging through spring security sources for a solid 12 hours and couldn't find it. I must've been looking at the completely wrong stuff :)

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. I'm a bit of a Spring Security fan. :)

Comment: I'm definitely becoming a fan as well. The more I use it, the more I like it.